# c# best way to match yahtzee

Tags: c#

In my project that i'm working on I have to match 5 numbers for yahtzee. So all these numbers have to be the same. Now I have thought about how to do this but i'm not sure about what the best and easiest way is. Sure I can write it all out but there has to be a shorter way.

I haven't written the code for the part that checks if yahtzee has been thrown. This is because I only can come up with one way and that is to write it all out.

Here's my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Opdr3
{
    class Program
    {
        struct YahtzeeGame
        {
            public int[] dobbelstenen;
            public Random rnd;

            public void Gooi()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    dobbelstenen[i] = Int32.Parse(rnd + "");
                }
            }

            public bool Yahtzee()
            {
                Here it has to check if all dobbelstenen[int]
                are the same
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // maak YahtzeeGame (struct) aan
            YahtzeeGame yahtzeeGame;

            // initialiseer struct-members
            yahtzeeGame.rnd = new Random();
            yahtzeeGame.dobbelstenen = new int[5];

            // probeer yahtzee te gooien
            int aantalPogingen = 0;
            do
            {
                // gooi alle dobbelstenen
                yahtzeeGame.Gooi();
                aantalPogingen++;
            } while (!yahtzeeGame.Yahtzee());

            // vermeld aantal pogingen voor yahtzee
            Console.WriteLine("Aantal pogingen nodig: {0}", aantalPogingen);

            // wacht op gebruiker
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What code do you already have? What specific issue do you have with it?

Comment: I really don't understand why it got downvoted so many times. If someone could explain this a bit then I'm happy to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a little loop:

```
public bool Yahtzee()
{
     // check if all dobbelstenen[int] are the same
     for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) // start with second dobbelstenen
     {
          if(dobbelstenen[i] != dobbelstenen[0]) return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

It simply compares second, third, ... against the first.

Comment: I really haven't thought it was this simple. This really helps clean up my code. Thanks